# Importing an XML File With Repeating Tags Including the Parent Info In Each Row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to import an xml and get a table or dataframe a row for every P and with a column for the HEAD of each parent (DIV6 and DIV8).

Example text below but see https://www.ecfr.gov/api/versioner/v1/full/2023-07-11/title-14.xml?part=27 for full xml.

```
<DIV5 N="27" TYPE="PART" VOLUME="1" hierarchy_metadata="{&quot;path&quot;:&quot;/on/_SUBSTITUTE_DATE_/title-14/part-27&quot;,&quot;citation&quot;:&quot;14 CFR Part 27&quot;,&quot;alternate_reference&quot;:&quot;FAR Part 27&quot;}">
    <DIV6 N="A" TYPE="SUBPART" hierarchy_metadata="{&quot;path&quot;:&quot;/on/_SUBSTITUTE_DATE_/title-14/part-27/subpart-A&quot;,&quot;citation&quot;:&quot;14 CFR Part 27 Subpart A&quot;,&quot;alternate_reference&quot;:&quot;FAR Part 27 Subpart A&quot;}">
        <HEAD>Subpart A—General</HEAD>
        <DIV8 N="27.1" TYPE="SECTION" VOLUME="1" hierarchy_metadata="{"path":"/on/_SUBSTITUTE_DATE_/title-14/section-27.1","citation":"14 CFR 27.1","alternate_reference":"FAR 27.1"}">
            <HEAD>§ 27.1 Applicability.</HEAD>
            <P>(a) This part prescribes airworthiness standards for the issue of type certificates, and changes to those certificates, for normal category rotorcraft with maximum weights of 7,000 pounds or less and nine or less passenger seats. </P>
            <P>(b) Each person who applies under Part 21 for such a certificate or change must show compliance with the applicable requirements of this part. </P>
            <P>(c) Multiengine rotorcraft may be type certified as Category A provided the requirements referenced in appendix C of this part are met. </P>
            <CITA TYPE="N">[Doc. No. 5074, 29 FR 15695, Nov. 24, 1964, as amended by Amdt. 27–33, 61 FR 21906, May 10, 1996; Amdt. 27–37, 64 FR 45094, Aug. 18, 1999] </CITA>
        </DIV8>
        <DIV8 N="27.2" TYPE="SECTION" VOLUME="1" hierarchy_metadata="{"path":"/on/_SUBSTITUTE_DATE_/title-14/section-27.2","citation":"14 CFR 27.2","alternate_reference":"FAR 27.2"}">
            <HEAD>§ 27.2 Special retroactive requirements.</HEAD>
            <P>(a) For each rotorcraft manufactured after September 16, 1992, each applicant must show that each occupant's seat is equipped with a safety belt and shoulder harness that meets the requirements of paragraphs (a), (b), and (c) of this section. </P>
            <P>(1) Each occupant's seat must have a combined safety belt and shoulder harness with a single-point release. Each pilot's combined safety belt and shoulder harness must allow each pilot, when seated with safety belt and shoulder harness fastened, to perform all functions necessary for flight operations. There must be a means to secure belts and harnesses, when not in use, to prevent interference with the operation of the rotorcraft and with rapid egress in an emergency. </P>
            <P>(2) Each occupant must be protected from serious head injury by a safety belt plus a shoulder harness that will prevent the head from contacting any injurious object. </P>
            <P>(3) The safety belt and shoulder harness must meet the static and dynamic strength requirements, if applicable, specified by the rotorcraft type certification basis. </P>
            <P>(4) For purposes of this section, the date of manufacture is either— </P>
            <P>(i) The date the inspection acceptance records, or equivalent, reflect that the rotorcraft is complete and meets the FAA-Approved Type Design Data; or </P>
            <P>(ii) The date the foreign civil airworthiness authority certifies that the rotorcraft is complete and issues an original standard airworthiness certificate, or equivalent, in that country. </P>
            <P>(b) For rotorcraft with a certification basis established prior to October 18, 1999— </P>
            <CITA TYPE="N">[Doc. No. 26078, 56 FR 41051, Aug. 16, 1991, as amended by Amdt. 27–37, 64 FR 45094, Aug. 18, 1999] </CITA>
            </DIV8>
    </DIV6>
</DIV5>
```

The code below was close and getting the DIV8 head at least and the last P. However I am then missing all the remaining P's.  I think the issue is the P tags are all named the same and there are multiple tags within an area, but I haven't been able to get a solution working.  Bonus points if you have a suggestion to get a column with the DIV6 head as well.  I am not tied to using pandas this was just the closest I got to having a solution.

```
import pandas as pd
x=pd.read_xml("https://www.ecfr.gov/api/versioner/v1/full/2023-07-11/title-14.xml?part=27",  xpath="/DIV5/DIV6//DIV8")

x.to_csv("Export.csv")
```

FYI I did notice there are a few italics markers through out the P tags, which I will deal with offline using a simple search and replace on the italics tags before processing the xml file so that isn't something that is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about using this XPath:

```
xpath="//*[HEAD]"
```

That will select all `DIV?` elements with a `HEAD`.
Problem will be that some have `P` where others don't...(I'm not familiar with pandas)

Comment: Thanks that does give all the head fields which is good! But they aren't in the same row as the p field then, I could possibly do something later to group.  But at least for pandas its every head field in the document in one column in order, but not grouped.